# getting 2 item instead of 1 mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i have problem i am using below script for merge tables and get data from mysql

```
    $myboxexi=mysql_query('select box.id,box.page_name,box.title,box.connect,box.type,box.uid,box.description,box.image,box.url,box.status,box.date,box.time
    from boxes as box left join page_boxes as pages on box.uid=pages.uid and pages.uid="'.$session_id.'"');
    while($my_boxi=mysql_fetch_array($myboxexi)){
    $title=$my_boxi['title'];
    $bid=$my_boxi['id'];
    $ptitle=$my_boxi['page_name'];
    $connect=$my_boxi['connect'];
    $type=$my_boxi['type'];
    $iuid=$my_boxi['uid'];
    $description=$my_boxi['description'];
    $image=$my_boxi['image'];
    $url=$my_boxi['url'];
    $appr=$my_boxi['status'];
    $date=$my_boxi['date'];
    $time=$my_boxi['time'];
    $myinfo=mysql_query('select * from users where id="'.$iuid.'"');
    $my_boxi_info=mysql_fetch_array($myinfo);
    $user_id=$my_boxi_info['id'];
    $user_name=$my_boxi_info['user_name'];
    $thmb=$my_boxi_info['thumb'];
    if(strpos($thmb,'https://') !== false) {
    $thmbs=$thmb;
    }else
    {
    $thmbs='images/thumbs/'.$thmb;
    }

}
```

its working fine but problem is i am getting double item like if i have 1 item then i get  2 item how can i solve this issue ?

Comment: Not from phpmyadmin - from mysql

Comment: Clear as mud for me.Could you post same sample data.

Comment: Maybe a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product problem?

Comment: Please, provide table structure and data

Comment: What the echo chamber is broken today?You have mysql injection problems,mysql is deprecated use mysqli or PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: @Mihai where i use mysqli ?:- s

Comment: @user4035 ok i am tryng

Answer (score 2):

I think you get 2 values because you have for example,element [0] and same element with key=name of column , so use only associatif result  :

**Change this :**

```
while($my_boxi=mysql_fetch_array($myboxexi)){
//data here.
}
```

**To this :**

```
while($my_boxi=mysql_fetch_array($myboxexi, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
//data here.
}
```

**Or to this**

```
while($my_boxi=mysql_fetch_assoc($myboxexi)){
//data here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array()` returns a dual-keyed array. e.g.

```
SELECT foo FROM bar


$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

will give you the array:

```
$row = array(
    0 => 'value from foo',
    'foo' => 'value from foo'
);
```

Since you're blindly looping on the returned array, you're looking up each of those "duplicate" results. If you only want ONE of the field types, try the dedicated functions, or the optional type argument,e .g

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // return only string keys
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC); // ditto
```

Comment: that's what i told , but i'm not good in english , they gave me -1

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are getting two items because two pages have the same user/session id that is being passed in:

```
select box.id, box.page_name, box.title, box.connect,box.type, box.uid, box.description,
       box.image, box.url, box.status,b ox.date,box.time
from boxes box left join
     page_boxes pages
     on box.uid = pages.uid and pages.uid = "'.$session_id.'"'
```

(To me, it is suspicious that you are setting `uid` -- which often means "user id" -- to a variable called `$session_id`, but that is another matter.)

If you only want one, add `limit 1` to the end of the query:

```
select box.id, box.page_name, box.title, box.connect,box.type, box.uid, box.description,
       box.image, box.url, box.status,b ox.date,box.time
from boxes box left join
     page_boxes pages
     on box.uid = pages.uid and pages.uid = "'.$session_id.'"'
limit 1;
```